# How to get transaction hash without waiting for await call?

Tags: transactions, ropsten, hash, async, sendsignedtransaction

for my demo I need the transaction hash instantly without waiting for callback of sync call.
Here my code:

```
aggiungiAllaBlockChain: async(u,n,c,e) => {

try {
  const web3     = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
  const contract_PartecipazioneContest = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(App.ABI_PartecipazioneContest), App.ADDR_PartecipazioneContest);
  const account  = App.account;

  //const receipt  = await App.sendUserInBlockChain(web3, account, contract_PartecipazioneContest.methods.addUser(u, n, c, e));
  
  const transaction = contract_PartecipazioneContest.methods.addUser(u, n, c, e);
  value = 0;

  const options = {
      to      : transaction._parent._address,
      data    : transaction.encodeABI(),
      gas     : await transaction.estimateGas({from: account.address, value: value}),
      gasPrice: await web3.eth.getGasPrice(),
      value   : value
  };
  const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, account.privateKey);
  const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
  .on('transactionHash', function(hash){
      console.log("hash on(transactionHash " + hash);
      return hash;

  });


  
} catch (error) {

  console.log("errore Aggiungi utente alla blockchain" + error)
}
}
```

I print the hash of my transaction but the return value doesn't work.

I have got this result using truffle but now I need this following this path *(not passing for meta mask)*

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The value returned by [signTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-accounts.html#signtransaction) contains the transactionHash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute `sendSignedTransaction` using the event emitter instead of using the promise.

See [this coding example](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth.html#id80) from the official documentation.

It is given for `sendTransaction`, but it works the same for `sendSignedTransaction`.

---

BTW, you may want to extend this:

```
await transaction.estimateGas({from: account.address})
```

To this:

```
await transaction.estimateGas({from: account.address, value: value})
```

Comment: @godvibration i have modified the code after your suggestion but the return values doesn't return to my front end call

Comment: @alfo888_ibg: You need to learn how to write asynchronous code. This is not the way. Follow the example. There is no `await` required when you use the event emitter.

Answer (score 2):

You can precalculate a transaction hash with all the transaction parameters and transaction signature. The transaction hash is the Keccak256 hash of the signed transaction: `Keccak256(RLP(nonce, gasPrice, gasLimit, to, value, data, v, r, s))`. Here's an example of how you could do it with `Web3` and `rlp`.

```js
import { encode } from 'rlp';

const transaction = {
  // Transaction parameters
  to: transaction._parent._address,
  gasPrice: await web3.eth.getGasPrice(),
  [...],

  // Signature
  v: ...,
  r: ...,
  s: ...
};

const rawTransaction = encode([transaction.nonce, transaction.gasPrice, transaction.gasLimit, transaction.to, transaction.value, transaction.data, transaction.v, transaction.r, transaction.s]);
const transactionHash = web3.sha3(rawTransaction);

console.log(transactionHash);
```

Comment: His/her code relies on using the current nonce (i.e., by not specifying `nonce`), so your suggestion might ultimately work out wrong for him/her, if they execute the actual transaction after executing some other transaction or transactions on the same account.